# Jsp algo to search multiple mysql database using user input

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I need a ALGO to create a **JSP** which will take in multiple user inputs and match them with multiple **MYSQL** tables.

Lets say I am trying to create a Disease Diagnosis System where the user will input their symptoms. So the JSP will take the inputs provided and match them with different tables. Each disease will have its own table and symptoms listed in it.So it will find the table it matches with and give the disease name as output.

I humbly apologize i have not been clear enough. *I am new to this*. Any help will be appreciated. **Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should rethink your data model. By general rule, you should not dynamically create or search through table names, but instead (when using RDBMSs) use relationships in order to dynamically relate concepts.

For your example, I suggest having a `Disease` table, a `Symptom` table, and a many to many relationship between them through an intermediate table (`disease_symptom`).

```
+-------------+     +---------------------+      +-------------+
|   Disease   |     |   Disease_Symptom   |      |   Symptom   |
+-------------+     +---------------------+      +-------------+
| id : int    |_____| disease : int (FK)  |______|id: int      |
|name: str    |     | symptom : int (FK)  |      |name: str    |
|             |     |                     |      |             |
+-------------+     +---------------------+      +-------------+
```

That way you could make a query something like this:

```
SELECT
    D.id, D.name
FROM
    Disease D
        JOIN Disease_Symptom DS ON (D.id = DS.disease)
        JOIN Symptom S ON (DS.symptom = S.id)
WHERE
    {user_input} = S.name;
```

Or you can use some ORM to find related objects to the symptoms that match your user's input.

**NOTE**: It's been a long time since I wrote a raw SQL query, so please if im wrong, correct me ;)

Comment: That's a nice take on the data model.. Maybe i should try rethinking it!

Comment: Can you provide me with some example of this kind? It will be a great help!!

Comment: sir thanks for the rapid reply..but there are few problems which i can't solve it..1.why are you performing a join using DS table?  2. D table will contain all the disease name and S table will contain all symptoms.. So what is the function of the DS table ? and what should it contain? thank you

Comment: @SupriyoRoy: Hi! `DS` table will model the many to many relationship between `D` and `S` table. Read [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) for more info on Relational database relationships. That article pretty much explains why we need the `DS` table. Sorry for the delay on the response.